# java.lang.NullPointerException while executing second @test annotated method using Selenium TestNG and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

java.lang.NullPointerException while executing second @test annotated method using Selenium TestNG and Java

Code trial:

```
public class Dropdown {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void Lanchdriver()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.suzukimotorcycle.co.in/find-dealer");
        WebElement dropdown1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dealer_touch_points']"));
        dropdown1.click();
        Select select = new Select (dropdown1);
        select .selectByVisibleText("Suzuki Premium Dealers");
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void select_dealer()
    {
        WebElement State_Dropdown =driver.findElement(By.id("dealer_state"));
        Select State_Select =new Select (State_Dropdown);
        State_Select.selectByValue("27");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
FAILED: select_dealer java.lang.NullPointerException at myNewPackage.Dropdown.select_dealer(Dropdown.java:47)
```

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: FAILED: select_dealer
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at myNewPackage.Dropdown.select_dealer(Dropdown.java:47)

Answer (score 0):

You already have declared a global instance of *WebDriver* i.e. **`driver`** as in:

```
WebDriver driver;
```

So you need not create any more method level instances of *WebDriver* and continue using the same instance of *WebDriver* with global scope i.e. **`driver`**.

---

### Solution

You need to remove the word `WebDriver` from the line `WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();` within `select_dealer()` method. Hence, effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update below line from beforeTest method

```
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

to

```
driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

because in your case scope will be limited to that BeforeMethod only. If you want to use same instance outside then declare at class level.

in your case, after execute beforeMethod your driver value got null. that is why getting nullpointer in Test method.